# drop_duplicates within a set

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking at a group of temporary employees in a DataFrame. I am using Pandas and I need to drop duplicates within the set for each person.  So for Greene, I would only want one unique date from the `apnt_ymd` column. There are two `2012-04-08` dates in the set and I would only need one.

In the past I was helped with something similar that looked at the min (and max by using idxmax) date within the data set by using the following code:

```
first_apt = df.loc[df.groupby('ssno')['apnt_ymd'].idxmin()]
```

I need something similar that will take out all the duplicate dates within the data set.

How can I use the `drop_duplicates` method to remove all the duplicate dates for each persons set of records? Or is there another way - such as apply?

```
ssno    nm_emp_lst  nm_emp_fst  apnt_ymd
299769   123456789   GREENE  ALTON  2014-05-04
192323   123456789   GREENE  ALTON  2013-04-07
192324   123456789   GREENE  ALTON  2012-04-08
192324   123456789   GREENE  ALTON  2012-04-08
102872   123456789   GREENE  ALTON  2011-04-10
175701   987654321   DUBE    JEFF   2013-04-21
177583   777888999   IRVING  SARA   2013-05-13
4785     777888999   IRVING  SARA   2012-05-16
222300   444444444   LEMERE  GEORGE 2013-04-14
24386    444444444   LEMERE  GEORGE 2012-03-25
24434    444444444   LEMERE  GEORGE 2011-05-08
```

Comment: Does this do what you want: `df.drop_duplicates(['nm_emp_lst','apnt_ymd'])`?

Comment: I think it worked.  I'm going to export and then verify my data..  Here is the code I used from your code above:  research.loc[research.apnt_ymd.drop_duplicates(take_last=False).index].sort('ssno')[:10]

Comment: Could you check my answer also, my first comment was posted without reading your requirements correctly, I think my answer should solve your problem, thanks.

Comment: The column I am looking at is a persons hiring date.  They can be hired multiple times in a year and seasonal as well, but never for the same date. The problem I initially had was that I had ten years worth of data.  When I used remove duplicates for a column it would remove all duplicates so it would remove someones hiring date if it was the same as another persons hiring date.

Comment: The code didn't work.  I've edited my initial question to try an make it more clear.

Comment: Sorry you want just unique dates for 'apnt_ymd' column or you want all unique combinations of 'ssno' and 'apnt_ymd', your question is not very clear to me, can you show desired output thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63401/discussion-between-user2201603-and-edchum).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then you can use [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html#pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates) on the dataframe, passing a list of the columns you want to check for duplicates:

```
In [31]:

df.drop_duplicates(['nm_emp_lst','apnt_ymd'])
Out[31]:
        id       ssno nm_emp_lst nm_emp_fst    apnt_ymd
0   299769  123456789     GREENE      ALTON  2014-05-04
1   192323  123456789     GREENE      ALTON  2013-04-07
2   192324  123456789     GREENE      ALTON  2012-04-08
4   102872  123456789     GREENE      ALTON  2011-04-10
5   175701  987654321       DUBE       JEFF  2013-04-21
6   177583  777888999     IRVING       SARA  2013-05-13
7     4785  777888999     IRVING       SARA  2012-05-16
8   222300  444444444     LEMERE     GEORGE  2013-04-14
9    24386  444444444     LEMERE     GEORGE  2012-03-25
10   24434  444444444     LEMERE     GEORGE  2011-05-08
```

**EDIT**
based on our private chat it looks the following is what you want:

```
In [89]:

df.drop_duplicates(['ssno','apnt_ymd'])
Out[89]:
        id       ssno nm_emp_lst nm_emp_fst    apnt_ymd
0   299769  123456789     GREENE      ALTON  2014-05-04
1   192323  123456789     GREENE      ALTON  2013-04-07
2   192324  123456789     GREENE      ALTON  2012-04-08
4   102872  123456789     GREENE      ALTON  2011-04-10
5   175701  987654321       DUBE       JEFF  2013-04-21
6   177583  777888999     IRVING       SARA  2013-05-13
7     4785  777888999     IRVING       SARA  2012-05-16
8   222300  444444444     LEMERE     GEORGE  2013-04-14
9    24386  444444444     LEMERE     GEORGE  2012-03-25
10   24434  444444444     LEMERE     GEORGE  2011-05-08
```

Comment: Thanks EdChum, yes df.drop_duplicates(['ssno','apnt_ymd']) seems to work.